# How to deal with the scrapy Itemloader()

Tags: python, scrapy

How to express this

```
item[field_name]=response.xpath('//*[@calss="title name "]/a/span').xpath('string(.)')
```

into this?

```
l=ItemLoader(item=ConccreseItem(),response=response)
l.add_xpath('field_name','//*[@class="title name"]/a/span')
```

how to add the .string('.') into the second expression?

Comment: Do you expect 1 or more values from the the first xpath() call? If only 1 is expected, you can use `response.xpath('string(/some/location/path)')`

Comment: I expect 2 values ,I also want to pass the argument to xpath(),only use one xpath()to fix the first line.

Comment: how to top it ?

Comment: I'm not an itemloader user myself, but you may want to try `.add_value(field_name, response.xpath('//*[@calss="title name "]/a/span').xpath('string(.)'))`

Comment: @paultrmbrth thanks,I have been thougt this way,but I suspect that its type ,now you perfectlty help me !Thank U